# Do moderators have a way to tell the difference between two users with the same username?

Tags: discussion

I recently discovered [this person](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32440/christianity-science) on the main SE, and I noticed that person called itself "Anonymous". Same as me. Do moderators have a way to tell the difference between that guy and me?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they do.  An account's display name can be changed and multiple accounts can have the same name.  Actually, anyone can tell the difference by your user#

Here's you: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4789/anonymous

And here's the other Anon:  https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14873/anonymous

(I'll only leave my display name as it is temporarily.  Edit: Rats, it looks like there's caching and my display name here hasn't changed to Anonymous like it now is on the main site.)

Comment: There's also the different avatar and reputation points!

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

Your user ids are different. It's in the link. Even if your avatars are the same. We also have access to some other information (things like your email and IP) if we're too concerned about the same accounts.